# How to find stale news using Cognitive Bing News Search API

Tags: search, azure-cognitive-services, bing-api, feed

I am currently using the v5.0 version of the Bing News Search API to do news search. Have a requirement to identify if the news being searched has gone stale. For ex: If i have already searched in the morning for a given news with the query parameters -  freshness set to "day" and if i again search in the evening with the same parameter, how can I identify what's the latest news which was not provided when i searched in the morning taking into consideration the Use & Display requirements of the bing news search API - (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/bing-news-search/useanddisplayrequirements).

Comment: Maybe the `sortBy` query param can help. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/rest/api/cognitiveservices/bing-news-api-v7-reference#query-parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using "datePublished" field and checking whether that piece was published post your previous search instance. You can use "sortBy" parameter if looking for trending news, which will give you the latest news on top. More info on these parameters can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cognitiveservices/bing-news-api-v7-reference